# Is it possible to reduce the size of a markdown html-report by including only specific parts of a package?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

Is there a  way to reduce the filesize of a R Markdown html-report by including only needed functions (e.g. plotly scatterplot) in the result file. My Report is self contained.

By creating a new R Markdown the resulting file size is ~735 KB. By adding a new chunk with a simple plotly plot the file size increases to ~4.834 KB.

````
```{r additional plotly example}
plotly::plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly gives you the possibility to leverage threw different bundles.

This is done by `partial_bundle()`.
The different sizes of the bundles can be found here:

- https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md#partial-bundles

For further information:

- https://plotly-r.com/performance.html
- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.9.0/topics/partial_bundle

Comment: how to achieve the same in plotly python?